# Send Email from android Using Firebase

Tags: android, email, firebase, jakarta-mail

Can we send emails within android using firebase , i have tried several libraries like [GmailBackground](https://github.com/yesidlazaro/GmailBackground),[BackgroundMail](https://github.com/kristijandraca/BackgroundMailLibrary), custom method of **Javax** to send mail , but unable to send any email ,not even a simple one.

So I wonder if Firebase give such a feature , it would be great ?
[Firebase Email Sending Blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/email-notifications-with-firebase_90.html) is showing empty is i think deleted , but why?

if you have any working source or tutorial to sent an email with attachment , it would be great , thanks

Comment: well i expected , it to be down voted because most people are offering paid services and they don't want user to send email using common libraries

Comment: I don't know why anyone would want to downvote this. Good question, and I wish to see a feature like that added to Firebase.

Comment: So anyone , know how to send an email from android in whole stack overflow?

Comment: What I can think of is to use HTTP mail sending feature of something like mailgun, so if you use something like AngularJS, you can read on how to go about it. Just a hint.

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching this all day...

## Option with third-party: SendGrid.com

There's actually a blog post by Tyson Bailey where he explains how he managed to get that done using SendGrid.com (**monthly fee**) here:
http://blog.onaclovtech.com/2014/07/emailster.html

It even includes the link to a Git he created upon it.

The solution in fact uses AngularJS as @Rexford mentioned in his comment.

Other options... None that I know for the moment, and am exactly researching upon a solution through GCP.

I can tell you they have been working since 2014 on something called "Triggers" that would allow triggering API actions from the database changes (which would helps lot), but seems to have been merged into Google Cloud Functions lately which is in Alpha by the time.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that as of a few days ago Firebase does now support sending emails... Obviously not from Android - that would be horrible - but from Firebase Fucntions - see [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think Firebase support that yet..
You can use maligun service with this library for now. I have tested, it works.

https://github.com/sargue/mailgun

https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#how-to-start-sending-email